# Ubuntu 12.04 Google Chome - Email links don't open Thunderbird

Tags: google-chrome, thunderbird

Just upgraded to ubuntu 12.04 and installed Google Chrome and Thunderbird.

When I click on an email address link in google chrome it does nothing most of the time but some of the time it opens a new chrome tab and signs me into googlemail, but in Ubuntu 11.10 it would open Thunderbird to write the email.

How do I get Thunderbird to open to write the email?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your preferred email client is now 'Chrome' instead of 'Thunderbird'. To change that, perform the following steps:

- Open 'System-Settings'

[image]

- Click on 'Details'

[image]

- On the left side of the window, click on 'Default Applications'
- On the mail option between browser and calendar, select 'Thunderbird'

[image]

- Close the window

Hope that helps

--EDIT--

Another part to look at that **Peter** found was the following solution:

- Right click on the 'mailto' link
- Find 'Open Link With'
- Select 'Configure'

[image]

- Remove any **Protocol Handler** types that you don't want to use like 'mailto' or 'webcal'

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help but that isn't the problem - I have actually found the issue - but couldn't post my own solution because I don't have a high enough rating.

Comment: The solution is to right click on the email link in chrome and then remove the default as gmail and then it resets it's to the settings you mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks Peter for that update. I have updated my entry to reflect what you have found. I noticed it to just after I came back to check up on this entry.

Comment: How do you paste screen prints in your replies - when I try I doesn't work? Totally as a side question!

Comment: When answering a question, you should see text that says 'img'. When you click on that, you will have two options to place in a picture: 1) download locally from your computer. 2) Use an image that is online. When selecting an image, it must be in a format that works like jpg, png, etc... Once done, you will see something like so: ![enter image description here][1] at the bottom of the screen, you will see something like this: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/S7pQz.jpg